# How do I switch from ActionBarActivity to AppCompatActivity in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an android project open, as well as the appcompat_v7 project that is automatically opened when you start an android project. In the MainActivity.java it defaults to importing and extending ActionBar Activity (I believe from the appcompat_v7 project)

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
```

However, ActionBarActivity is deprecated. I've found online that you're supposed to use AppCompatActivity instead, but I can't find, anywhere, how to make the switch with Eclipse.

Is it a matter of changing code? Downloading and importing files? I can't get any information online.

Thanks.

Comment: Add `import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;` to your imports (assuming you have the Android Support Libraries installed, which you probably do) and change `extends ActionBarActivity` to `extends AppCompatActivity`. That should hopefully work.

Answer (score 0):

Well `ActionBarActivity` extends `AppCompatActivity` so there should not be any difficulty in switching! It should be a matter of importing the right class!